# Add MountOptions to Kubernetes ingress rule from cli

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

I have a PV/PVC in my kubernetes cluster.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

I want to externally add `mountOptions` to all PVs like below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0003
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  storageClassName: slow
  mountOptions:
    - hard
    - nfsvers=4.1
  nfs:
    path: /tmp
    server: 172.17.0.2
```

Is there any way I can achieve this using `kubectl` cli like we add annotations to ingress rules and pods?

Comment: You want to add `mountOptions` to every PV in the cluster? What about PVs that already has some `mountOptions` provided - do you want to replace them or add to existing?

Comment: @Mikolaj S
No pvs in existing name space has mount options so it will be okay to add mountoptions to all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`kubectl patch` command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/manage-kubernetes-objects/update-api-object-kubectl-patch/) to add `mountOptions` to existing PV in the cluster:

```
kubectl patch pv pv0003 --patch '{"spec": {"mountOptions": ["hard","nfsvers=4.1"]}}'
```

If you want to add `mountOptions` to every PV  in the cluster you can use simple bash `for` loop and `kubectl patch` command:

```
for pv in $(kubectl get pv --no-headers -o custom-columns=":metadata.name"); do kubectl patch pv $pv --patch '{"spec": {"mountOptions": ["hard","nfsvers=4.1"]}}'; done
```